# Drupal Facets nested content type

Tags: views, search

I have content Type "School", that has title, some term reference fields (geographic region,for example).
A School can has one or more (multiple) Clusters

Cluster is another content type that is being referenced from the School content type.

Each cluster has 
  type (1 to 4)
  year (2011 till 2014)
  checkbox fields (yes, no)

What would be the best way to structure the data if I want to setup the filters with search/facets api, so that I can filter on **Cluster's** "year", checkboxes,as well as the School georegion.

Thanks in advance !.

Comment: Can you clarify what a cluster is? is it a drupal entity?

Comment: Hi, Cluster is another content type that is being referenced from the School content type

Comment: ok, but then, in your search index, if you index referenced entities, you should have access to the fields of the clusters, so you should be able to add facets on them. I've done that using solr/search_api/search_api_solr

Comment: There is a problem that when the filters from the referenced entities are selected, the facets from the original entity (node:school) are not visible, and furthermore it gives me completely wrong data. 
I am not using solr ....
Only database search